# Why do answers, questions, comments, suddenly disappear (and sometimes reappear)?

Tags: discussion, moderation

It might be regardable as meta-question, but just not finding any access to this area here:

It happens that answers, questions, comments, suddenly disappear, mostly at the same time of the day and under similar, seemingly elementary conditions. Generally just to let you know and that, if you wish to possible solve a possible technical problem, or problem in sequences of possibilities for you meta investigations and possible best welfar (no need or wish to solve any of possible lose from my person side, and just because acting right is only posdible when knowing about certain circumstances):

- Are there possible elementary problems with the question and answering possibilities?

Sometimes content appears, disappears, and again... but such can be of course also just a "personal", individual perception, kammic bodily, verbal or mental phenomena, not a "collective" frutation of a certain group. Maybe even the deeds of envy or angry gotten hungry ghosts. Who knows? :-) Which would call for the implementing of a sacrify shrine for the placeholders (called owner/lords of water and earth, "protective/defending" spirits with strong upanissaya of places.)

Best success with it, and may it not even have touched you here, or gave/give reasons.

Again, no demands or wishes, but just to let it be known, as a matter of appreciation of ALL your skillful works and efforts here.

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma, not meant for commercial purpose and other low wordily gains by means of trade and exchange]*

Comment: Sabba sankhara anatta. Vayadhammā saṅkhārā appamādena sampādethā

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not related to the Buddhist teachings

Comment: **"I was talking recently to someone who had given a gift to a lay-run meditation center last year. He came back this year to find that it disappeared. When he asked the people at the center about this they said: "Well, that's impermanence (*Sabba sankhara anatta*)." Which (in this relation, as excuse for bad) is not the [Dharma of the Buddha...](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/sensitivity_en.html).** "I'm voting to close...", how supprising... Element (Ddhatu). Could it be that this is the elementary problem? Tendencies?

Comment: ... **There is a danger in trying to boil everything down to just a few principles.** Like the idea that all the Dharma teachings come down to the three characteristics: "You just have to accept that things are impermanent, stressful and non-self, just let go at that.

The Buddha didn't teach that way. That was a particular teaching to be applied in particular circumstances. And there are much larger frameworks which include a much larger picture, it means he actually taught Dharma and Vinaya. We tend to forget that.

And the Vinaya's not just rules, but protocols, patterns for behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I think that's not a "technical problem" -- it's not a "bug", rather it's a built-in (intended, purposeful) "feature" of the software.

- **People (any/all users)** sometimes delete their own posts (the software allows them to, and they do):

  - Anyone who posts an answer can delete their own answer (and any comments under that answer) -- moderators will usually ([not always](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94421/139866)) allow users to delete their own answers
  - Anyone who posts a question can delete their own question, if (and only if) the question hasn't been answered yet by anyone
  - Any user can delete their own comment[s]
- **Moderators** can delete anything or everything, including other people's questions, answers, and comments).

  Moderators will (should) usually post a comment if they delete an answer or a question. That comment will be visible to high-reputation users -- see also [Why can we see deleted answers?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1605/254) (but not visible to you because you keep starting new user IDs instead of accumulating reputation).

  Moderators usually don't comment if or when they delete a comment; so comments may disappear without notice.

The only person who can delete something (question, answer, or comment) is:

- The author (of that question, answer, or comment)
- A moderator
- [Theoretically a quorum of high-reputation users can delete someone else's down-voted answer but that happens rarely if ever on this site].

So you can assume that, if something disappears, it was deleted by the author or by a moderator.

Occasionally people delete their own answers after you comment on their answers, perhaps because they:

- Realise that their answer was wrong
- Decide that their answer was unwelcome
- Find that easier than (preferable to) trying to reply to the comments.
- Want time to edit it privately, before they undelete it later
- [or some other personal reason, I don't know]

Content that's deleted isn't really deleted. Deleted answers are "hidden" but are still visible to the the author, to moderators, and to high-reputation users. Deleted answers may be undeleted by the author and/or by moderators (depending on who deleted them), and so they may re-appear.

Deleted comments are visible only to moderators.

If you notice content which you authored being deleted, and if it wasn't you who deleted it, then it must have been deleted by a moderator for some reason:

- If it was an answer you'll still see it (probably with a comment from the moderator to say why they deleted it).
- If it was a comment, well, it's just gone. Moderators often delete comments (or move comments to chat) because the comments on the site aren't meant to be used for "secondary discussion", not for arguments, etc.

If a moderator does delete a comment of yours, please take the hint and don't repost that same comment again.

Comment: Sadhu for the great effort to try to explain, Nyom Chris. Obiviously Chris has much joy in giving information of site and sequences. Mudita. 3 Things: 1. "**Anyone who posts an answer can delete** their own answer (and any comments under that answer) -- **moderators will usually (not always) allow users to delete** their own answers", ther seems to be a contradiction. 2. Could it be that not- members can technical not delete their answer/question (or wher would a link for such be found). How many reputation would a non-mod need to act like phantomas? Can "power" be seen? Mod-actors be known?

Comment: In regard of improvements ot elementary sequences, the answers possibilities are not used, but merely just like in a help-center answered. So the main "gift", since not a matter of "gone, thats nature" or carelessness, is not addressed here. No reflections, but "just" it IS such and such.

Comment: 1. Any user can always easily delete any answer of their own (for example you ought to be able to see a "delete" link at the bottom of all your answers). If a user does delete an answer of their own, moderators will see that deletion and they will usually do/say nothing about it. If a user tries to delete many or all of their past answers, then moderators might see that as "vandalism" and prevent it (e.g. moderators might undelete the answer; and/or delete the user but not the answer, so that the answer remains but no longer associated with the user).

Comment: See [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/139866) for further details.

Comment: `the answers possibilities are not used, merely just like in a help-center answered ... No reflections, but "just" it IS such and such` Yes (a lot of my written answers are like that).

Comment: Found this (our of protocol-) way to forward possible good if known info's and comments: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlOSY.jpg **[Please stop posting Meta-content on the main site. Thanks.](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/23458/are-there-possible-elementary-problems-with-the-question-and-answering-possibili)**

Comment: Yes you have to be a logged-in user to post on Meta, with a reputation of at least 5 ([see here for details](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta)). That means Meta is available to every user who is a member of the site (i.e. who has posted on the main site and received at least one up-vote from another user). I guess restricting it to only logged-in users helps reduce spam or something (e.g. other off-topic posts) on Meta. Do you find it hard to log-in? I notice your user account is "unregistered" ...

Comment: "you ought to be able to see a "delete" link at the bottom of all your answers", is that for sure? Nicca: "Yes (a lot of my written answers are like that)." As the next tries... answer. It IS "me, my self and I", unchangeable, real. :-) Don't' reflect! D.O. could be seen, just give sanna-khandha (remember-aggregat) value.

Comment: ... see e.g. See e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68524/what-does-it-mean-when-someones-an-unregistered-user and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42267/how-to-register-my-unregistered-account and so on. I think that to "register" a user account, you may need to give an email address or something like that.

Comment: "Yes you have to be a logged..." so can Chris Inform @Lanka that (like most), a not favoring his wishes have deeper reasons which are always not like assumed motivated. My person can like often, not fullfil, either technical or ethical, certain wishes and request.

Comment: And again, like told in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlOSY.jpg), the links from and back main and meta, or missing on the "new" theme.

Comment: Assuming you have an email address, you may be able to register it here: https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register ... after which you can log-in.

Comment: taking to arrange ones properbly easier ways, is not proper, as being member or to sign contracts not really is. Is already "hard" on the edge as it is, if remember older discussions, infos, Nyom Chris. You are no owner here at all, so you properply could not give what is not yours, given to you, personal, knowingly. In all terms one depends on attentivness and hostility of others. Sometimes one stands therefor in the rain, while other sit under a roof and talk theoretical. Thats ok.

Comment: Btw. "This question came from our site for **people practicing** or **interested** in Buddhist philosophy, teaching, and **practice**." Sure? And, if certain people (can) act like mods, the effects will nevertheless fall back on the mods, since it is assumed that they are in charge. Which could be unpleasant, but a cause of not taking, showing distance, aside of not collective acts and their effects.

Comment: [This page](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) lists the site's moderators.

Comment: That means 4000 is equal moderator on action, and people with 5000 are even able to look into privacy of useres... holly, and their act will be 90% count just on offical faces. Well, good conduct helps nevertheless. In regard of wellbeing in the current, one migh suffer if hoping for good estimate, be suspected by fellows to accosiate with certain acts. Well, it should be so. Profit is always earned best by lack of awarness by the consumer.

Comment: Considered this a little, meaning to accept being voluntary under control of certain "emements" who are not shameful to ly, steal, kill impose seperations... it's maybe really better to walk on here. There are certain things which should be abounded by avoiding. "... [fermentations to be abandoned](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/mn/mn.002.than_en.html) by avoiding? ... in the sorts of unsuitable seats, wandering to the sorts of unsuitable habitats, and associating with the sorts of bad friends that would make his knowledgeable friends in the holy life suspect him of evil conduct."

Comment: Propably certain strong rebukes and approaches have been not on account of the mods in the past... so for all cases where such was unreasonable met, a "pardon" would be proper, but it should be not forgotten, that assosiation, even if can be just assumed, with fools brings pain.

Comment: Just found the new placing of the link to meta, for the case you like to inform the community members so that they could find here: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYa1R.jpg

Comment: @SamanaJohann Thank you, I didn't realise that was difficult. I think there's also another link to Meta under that question-mark icon on the toolbar (see the answers to [How do users navigate to Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302510/139866) for further illustrations).